# Trying to convert a DXF file from Release 12 (AC1009) to at least 2000 (AC1015) progrematically

Tags: version, upgrade, autocad, dxf

So the company I work for creates countertops and has there own logic and app in Java written in house that makes our dxf files for our countertops. We are now going to be outsourcing some of our work and the company we are outsourcing to is taking our dxf files and going to be using them. Like stated in the title, our current ACADVER is set to "AC1009", which is the most bare minimum level of autocad that can be read by viewers. The company wants us to upgrade our dxf files to a newer version, preferably the most recent version (AC1032) but they are willing to accept something as low as AC1015 which is the 2000/2002 version.

If I go in the dxf file and manually adjust the version number to a newer version, it has an error opening the dxf file (figured it wouldn't work but hoped it would be that easy). I was curious from a super base level if anyone has any knowledge or references to UPGRADING your dxf version, not downgrading, because I have seen a lot of downgrading your version, adding certain fields if they are missing, etc etc.

The start of my code is

```
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1009
```

And I would change that ACADVER right there to other version and none worked. I have also removed everything but the Entities section and it opens as that lowest default version without those included. Any help would be amazing from you guys :D.

I tried removing sections (HEADER/TABLES/LAYERS) and leaving ENTITIES in, I have tried adjusting the ACADVER to newer versions. I have ran through the code and tried using an online converter and reading the dxf files side by side and see how they converted it to a newer version but the online converters adds so much mumbo jumbo that its hard to decipher anything it added. I just want to be able to convert it to a newer version of a dxf file!

Comment: You could always approacha company to open / save your DXF files as different versions for a modest fee rather than code it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as easy as you might think. Going from DXF R12 to DXF R2000 is much bigger than changing some header variables.

Briefly the most important requirements:

- all DXF entities and table entries need handles
- DXF tags in DXF entities have be grouped and separated by subclass markers, group code 100
- new required `CLASSES` section
- new required `OBJECTS` section
- new required `BLOCK_RECORD` table in the `TABLES` section
- each `BLOCK` requires a `BLOCK_RECORD` entry

AutoCAD is very lenient with DXF R12 format, in DXF R2000 it changed to "very pedantic" which makes such conversion cumbersome as AutoCAD's feedback in the form of error messages and crashes are not very helpful.

You have at least 3 options:

1. learn all the DXF R2000+ features and write your own program
2. use the very good, reliable and free OpenDesign Alliance [FileConverter](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/oda_file_converter) for win/linux/mac
3. use my [ezdxf](https://pypi.org/project/ezdxf/) Python package

Python script to convert a DXF R12 file to DXF R2018:

```py
from ezdxf import recover

# Use the recover module to load the DXF files, the input files may not be error free:
doc, _ = recover.readfile("r12.dxf")
doc.dxfversion = "R2018"
doc.saveas("R2018.dxf")
```

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Have I anything to do to accept the edit? I don't understand the interface of SO!

Comment: No, I have enough reputation to edit questions and answers so it does not need to be approved or anything. 

Comment: ... just because I don't see the changes applied on the regular website

Comment: There is - I added markdown to your text, like `CLASSES` and `OBJECTS`. You can click the link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76077857/revisions.

Comment: ~~I saw the changes on the revision page, but will I never see this changes on the regular page?~~ The changes are really, really hard to see on the dark them :)

Comment: ... and  strike through seems also not work :) and comments can only be edited for 5 minutes -- I really start to hate this site.

Comment: I use dark theme all the time. And yes, comments can only be edited for a few minutes.

Comment: I see them on the regular page.